# Pass Var to method for file upload in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a method to upload a file that is standard for my solution.  However, I cannot find how to pass the file to another method.

Here is the code I have:

```
var file = Request.Files[0];

if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
         _fileName = new FileController().UploadFile(file, "Tickets", ticketReturn.TicketNumber.ToString());
}



public string UploadFile(File file, string SubPath, string folder)
{


      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

      string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaFolder"] + "\\" + SubPath + "\\" + fileName;

      var FullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);

      file.SaveAs(fullPath);


      return fileName;
}
```

The issue I am having is I cannot pass a var to the method, so I tried passing a file but that gives me an error stating no overload method has those arguments.  How can I change it so I can pass in the file?

Comment: im guessing here that the `File` type in the `file` parameter is `System.IO.File`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White - so what would I want?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong parameter type in your `UploadFile()` method.

Items in `Request.Files` collection is of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, not `File`. So update your method to have the correct type for your parameter.

```
public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string SubPath, string folder)
{
   //do something with the file now and return some string
}
```

Also, I am not quite sure why you are creating a new object of your `FileController()`.(*Are you calling it from a different contorller?*) If both methods are in the same class, You can simply call the method without creating a new object.

```
public ActionResult CreateUserWithImage()
{
   if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count>0)
   {
        var f = Request.Files[0];
        UploadFile(f,"Some","Abc");
   }
   return Content("Please return something valid here");
}      

private string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string SubPath, string folder)
{
   //do something with the file now and return some string
}
```

If you are calling this method from a different controller action, you should consider moving this UploadFile method to a different common class(*UploadManager.cs ?* ) which can be used from any controller you want(*You can inject it via dependency injection or worst case, manually create an object of this new class in your controllers as needed*). You should not call one controller from another.